# Latex class from remote source?

Tags: latex, pdflatex

In order to share a bibtex library across projects, it's possible to link to a remote resource using at < some url > using,

```sh
\addbibresource[location=remote]{< some url >}
```

This is a really nice method when collaborating on multiple projects with a shared reference library.

I'd love to do the same with a custom document class file. The closest answer to this question I could find was discussed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/264178/includeing-a-remote-file) but it seems no solution was found.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: I would use some version control system like git for the class, then you can use git to make sure that you have the newest version of your class file on your computer

Comment: Thanks, Sam. I was hopping to be able to link the class file from a remote location when collaborating. I appreciate the suggestion!